# Read content from .epub file

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, filereader, epub, epub3

I am new to epub and I have to write code which take epub file(.epub) as an input and preview that file using regular java and response like epub reader.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Epublib](http://www.siegmann.nl/epublib). Epublib is a java library for managing epub files. It’s capable of reading and writing epub files programmatically. API docs are available [here](http://www.siegmann.nl/static/epublib/apidocs/).